# Finding the curve length

Tags: calculus, integration

I am solving some curve length questions and came across this question:

$$ x = \frac{y^3}{6} + \frac{1}{2y} ;  2<= y <=3 $$

I know how to solve for the curve length when they provide y equals to something, however, i am not sure on how to solve x equal to something. I have tried moving around the values and made y equal to x. However, then i am not sure on how to change the boundary value 2<= y <=3.

How do we go about solving for the curve length in such scenarios?

Hope I am clear with my question, if not, please drop me a comment and i will try to improve on it. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: The function $ \ x(y) \ $ _is_ one-to-one on the stated interval, but the inverse $ \ y(x) \ $ is going to be unpleasant to work with.  It will be rather easier to deal with the arclength integration over $ \ y \ $ than over $ \ x \ $ .  You would set up the integration as $  \ \int_2^3 \ \sqrt{ left( \frac{dx}{dy} \right)^2 \ + \ 1 } \ \ dy \ $ .

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are just labels. If you know how to solve for the curve length when $y = f(x)$ in the $xy$-plane, then you know how to solve for the curve length when $q = g(p)$ in the $pq$-plane, or when $א = ш(क)$ in the $אक$-plane. So maybe you can solve for the length of the curve $x = f(y)$ in the $yx$-plane.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Hmm..so i just differentiate the value and sub it into the curve length formula for (f'(x))?

Comment: It's $ \ \frac{dx}{dy} \ $ , so you will have $ \ f'(y) \ = \ \frac{1}{2} y^2 - \frac{1}{2y^2} \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should probably know the formula for arc length. There are multiple versions, of course, most commonly:

$$s=\int \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx$$
$$=\int \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2} dy$$
$$=\int \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2} dt$$

There are a lot of other ones... We can go a little crazier, of course....

$$s=\int \sqrt{\left(\frac{d\rho}{dt}\right)^2+\rho^2\sin^2\varphi\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2+\rho^2\left(\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\right)^2}$$

But yeah, don't worry about that. As for your problem, we'll just use the second equation (you can use the first, but $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is easier to obtain and you have an interval of $y$ so you clearly want the second one).

$$x = \frac{y^3}{6} + \frac{1}{2y}$$

Step one, find $\frac{dx}{dy}$. Simple enough:

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2y^2}$$

Now use the equation... Our bounds are $2 \le y \le 3$... Hence:

$$s=\int_2^3 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2y^2}\right)^2} dy$$

Integrating that is a big mess... Don't think any teacher would make you do that. Use a calculator to evaluate this and you'll get:

$$\therefore s=3.25$$

Comment: It is _not_ a big mess: this is a typical textbook exercise in which adding 1 to the binomial-square with a minus sign in it turns it into a binomial-square with a _plus_ sign.  The integrand is then a perfect square under a square-root and the result is simple to integrate.  The arclength is _exactly_ $ \ \frac{13}{4} \ $ , the value you found, and no approximation will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$s=\int^b_a\sqrt{\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2}=\int^b_a\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}^2\right)}\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: I believe you want to move the "square" exponent outside of the parentheses.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Ah, yes! Thank you. That's why I put the brackets around $dy/dx$ in the first place!